# Break instead of continue in loops in c?

Tags: c

Here, in this code for printing ramanujans number, im comfused that it should contain continue instead of break, cause we need to check all numbers in the input range and if we use break then the we'll come out of the loop instead of checking it with another number.
Can anyone explain this to me, why break instead of continue?

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int n,a,b,c,d,a3,b3,c3,d3;
    printf("Enter the limit");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(a=1;a<=n;a++)
    {
        a3=a*a*a;
        if(a3>n)
            break;
        for(b=a;b<=n;b++)
        {
            b3=b*b*b;
            if(a3+b3>n)
                break;
            for(c=a+1;c<=n;c++)
            {
                c3=c*c*c;
                if(c3>a3+b3)
                    break;
                for(d=c;d<=n;d++)
                {
                    d3=d*d*d;
                    if(c3+d3>a3+b3)
                        break;
                    if(c3+d3==a3+b3)
                    {
                        printf("%d=%d^3+%d^3=%d^3+%d^3\n",(a3+b3),a,b,c,d);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `continue` means go back to the start of the loop

Comment: `break` terminates the `for` loop. It's like a `goto` right _after_  the end of the loop. `continue` skips the rest of the loop, it's like a `goto` right _before_ the end of the loop.

Comment: `break` in stead of `continue` depends on the algorithm you want to implement.

Comment: @Nina No, it doesn't. It means jump to the end of the loop - which, for a `for` loop means go to the iteration statement.

Comment: @AdrianMole IS the start of the loop not the iteration statement?

Comment: @Nina No, the iteration statement is executed *after* each **iteration** of the loop. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/continue) describes `continue` pretty well.

Comment: @AdrianMole When I start of the loop I meant the iteration statement but I assumed it was a given.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are searching the numbers in increasing order.

Once `a3>n` (where `a3=a*a*a`) becomes true for some positive `a`, no `a` larger than that `a` will make the condition `a3>n` false (unless overflow happens).

Therefore you don't need to check larger values and using `break;` is proper.

We can say the same thing for the rest of loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i get it now. I miss understood the code :D